# Cygwinで‘mkstemp’ was not declared in this scopeというエラー

Tags: c++, cygwin

現在、Cygwinで[DUNE](https://www.dune-project.org/)と呼ばれるC++ベースの偏微分方程式を解くツールのインストールを進めているのですが、ビルドしようとした所、以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
‘mkstemp’ was not declared in this scope
```

調べた所、[mkstemp](https://kazmax.zpp.jp/cmd/m/mkstemp.3.html)とはLinuxのライブラリコール関数の様なのですが、Cygwinでこの関数が定義されたファイルを含むライブラリをビルドする方法ご存知の方居ましたら御教示頂け無いでしょうか？ちなみに、Cygwinのバージョンは以下の通りです。

```
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 A050946732 3.0.7(0.338/5/3) 2019-04-30 18:08 x86_64 Cygwin
```

Comment: [他のユーザーが再現しやすいよう](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)、できるだけ詳しい情報を含めましょう。現在の質問文を見た限りでは、DUNEのサイトからCore Releaseのアーカイブを落として試行錯誤しているのかな？という風に見えますが、コメントの内容を踏まえるとモジュールのビルドで躓いているという話なので、エラーメッセージだけをピンポイントで提示するのではなく、DLしたファイルの名前やバージョンも含めておくと誤解が減るかと思います。 / あと、Cygwin においては gcc も複数バージョンが用意されていたかと思うので、Cygwinのバージョンだけより gcc のバージョンも含めたほうがよいかなと。

Answer (score 0):

`DUNE` は [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) ベースなので `fseeko` とか `mkstemp` とか使ってないはずなんだけど。実際 `dune-common-2.6.0.tar.gz` 中には `find . -exec grep -n fseeko {} \;` で何もヒットしなかったっす (他は展開してない) オイラの見ている https://www.dune-project.org/ とは違うものなのかな？

cygwin 3.0.7(0.338/5/3) で次のプログラムは通ったっす。リンク先にも `#include <stdlib.h>` しろ、との説明ありますよね。

```
$ cat mkstest.c
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char temp[]="/tmp/mkXXXXXX";
    return mkstemp(temp);
}
$ gcc mkstest.c
$ ./a.exe
$ ls /tmp
mkCCxXft
$
```

# `$ dune-common-2.6.0/bin/dunecontrol all` がまともに通らないのでそれ以上追及する気にならない

---

`dune-grid-2.6.0/dune/grid/io/file/dgfparser/dgfparser.cc` 中に `HAVE_MKSTEMP` で条件分けされて `mkstemp()` と `std::tmpnam()` を使い分けている個所があります。

1. `mkstemp()` をやめて `std::tmpnam()` を使う

[c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) っぽくするならこっちだけど `man tmpnam` によると
https://ja.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/tmpnam
`tmpnam()` はかぶらなそうなファイル名を返すだけでファイルを作るわけではないので、他人がクリティカルなタイミングで同一名称のファイルを作ることができるとのこと。こっちで対処する場合は `config.h` 中から `#define HAVE_MKSTEMP 1` の行を手で削除すればよいです。

2. `mkstemp()` を使う

`dgfparser.cc` の先頭に

```
#if HAVE_MKSTEMP
#include <unistd.h>
#endif
```

なる行がありますが、これが多分間違いで `<stdlib.h>` でないといけないはず。 hpux11.11 の `man mkstemp` でも `<stdlib.h>` が指示されています。というわけでこれは DUNE の側のバグと言い切っちゃっていいでしょう。（ DUNE 側の都合で `<unistd.h>` を使っているのかもしれないが）ソースの手修正を行うことが適切だと思われます。

3. `tmpfile()` に書き直す

`mkstemp()` は古いので `tmpfile()` を使うよう直せと hpux11.11 は主張していますので、この際直してもよいかも。ただし `tmpfile()` `std::tmpfile()` が作ったファイルは自動削除されるので、恒久化の目的には使えません。

Comment: わざわざトライして頂きありがとうございます。言及されているプロジェクトが自分が今導入しようとしているものです。dune-commonはこのライブラリのコア部分で、この他にも複数のモジュールがあり、そのうちのdune-gridというモジュールをビルドしようとして、mkstempに関するエラーが発生しておりました。

Comment: [Core Modules/dune-grid](https://gitlab.dune-project.org/core/dune-grid)には含まれていますね。